# Rails Joins with Condition on Joined Table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using Rails 6. I have an `Order` table and an `Address` table. `Order` `has_many :addresses`.  Each order holds a reference to two address fields, one for billing and another for shipping. If the shipping record is the same as the billing record, then the `same_as_billing` field is set to `true` for the shipping address record and all address data is stored in the billing address record.

I'm trying to query all orders that have a logical shipping address with the country set to "United States". I would normally accomplish this with a regular joins like this:

```
Order.all.joins(:addresses).where(addresses: {address_type: "Shipping", country: "United States"})
```

However, because some shipping addresses might be flagged with `same_as_billing = true`, none of the address data is actually stored in those records and is instead stored in the billing address record. I'm not sure how to query shipping address records and then conditionally join the billing address records if `same_as_billing = true`. There are always two addresses associated with each `Order`.

Comment: I'm thinking you want something like an EXISTS subquery - can you please tell us what DB you are using and provide examples of the models so that we can test it out without having to recreate everything from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you should be able to use an `or` query to achieve this.

```
shipping_addresses = Order.all.joins(:addresses).where(addresses: { address_type: 'Shipping', country: 'United States' })
billing_addresses = Order.all.joins(:addresses).where(addresses: { address_type: 'Billing', country: 'United States', same_as_billing: true })

valid_addresses = shipping_addresses.or(billing_addresses)
```